# Asus battery health charging not working

Tags: asus-laptop, charging

I just downloaded the asus battery health charging app on microsoft store. The charging options are there not greyd ou, but when I plugged in it's still charging to 100%. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Please add more information to your post. Some screenshots would be useful.

Comment: @harrymc Hi. I'm using the vivobook X542UA. and the software stopped working after I reinstalled windows 10

Comment: I think that the version you got is for ZenBooks.

Comment: I looked at ASUS download page and it redirected me to Microsoft store

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Battery Health Charging app can't find it anywhere (Asus ux430UA)](https://superuser.com/questions/1251716/battery-health-charging-app-cant-find-it-anywhere-asus-ux430ua)

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, then I read a post on Reddit that claimed you needed to install something called the "ATK" package as well. This controls hotkey function, and apparently some part of the "Battery health charging" app. I downloaded the ATK pack from the ASUS website, and it did indeed unlock the choices (i.e. make them not greyed out anymore).

Enter your laptop model in the page linked here and you should be able to find the ATK package you need: https://www.asus.com/support/Download-Center/